# why kernel repositories' tags are different

Tags: git, tags, kernel

I'm going to develop my master thesis based on Linux Kernel.
There are two git repositories to find

https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

What I can't understand is that I couldn't find git [TAG] 3.10.10 in the 2nd but can't find it in the 1st but [TAG] 3.10

Can someone explain this for me?

Cheers!

Comment: Git repositories are all independent of one another. Why would you expect all tags to appear in every kernel git repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernels move from "prepatch" to "mainline" to "stable" as described in https://www.kernel.org/releases.html. Another helpful link is https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/development-process/2.Process.

The prepatch (3.X-rc) and mainline (3.X) tags are in the "torvalds" repository maintained by Linus Torvalds himself. The "stable" (3.X.Y) and "longterm" (3.X.Y) tags are in the "stable" repository, maintained by desginated maintainers.

The Torvalds "mainline" repository represents the latest patches and fixes. Kernel versions that pass some degree of testing are moved to the "stable" repository and tagged. Afterwards, bug fixes are sometimes backported from mainline versions to tagged "stable" versions.

Comment: What's the type for github? Is that long term?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds/linux looks like mainline to me. Is that the "github" you intended?